# Do we hate hats?

Tags: discussion, winterbash-2014

I saw [this Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10083/30879) on Arquade talking about Winterbash 2014

> We have been given the option this year to opt out of this year's Winterbash. The default is opt-in, so if we do nothing or can't decide, we will get hats. However if we decide that we definitely do not want hats, we can make sure the site remains hat-free until at least a year's time.

Now I am unsure if we have been given the option and I have a feeling [a certain someone](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/24/logan-m) who won [network wide last year](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network?page=1) may want to revive the madness if given the option

So a couple of questions.

1. do we have the option to opt-out of Winterbash 2014?
2. if we can opt-out, should we?

Comment: I think there should be more hat collusion this year.

Comment: Don't worry about me. It was my first time doing Winter Bash, so I had to go a bit crazy to get everything. Now that I have some experience with it and know what I'm doing, I shouldn't need to go as crazy to repeat my performance from last year.

Comment: That is Arqade*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a site, we will participate in the Winter Bash this year (unless serious objections are raised).

Each individual users have a "I hate hats" link that will opt him out of the event.

Comment: How do you have a "I hate hats" link? Is there a set URL we would use? Do we post it in the Bio section of our profile and if so does it matter where we place it?

Comment: If it's anything like last year, the "I hate hats" link will be at the footer of every page.